# Nessus No host data is available for this scan error

Tags: penetration-test, vulnerability-scanners, tcp

I encountered an error in a Nessus result.

> Error:
>        No host data is available for this scan.

I want to scan IP 192.16x.x.x with Nessus. I scan this IP with nmap and only 2 TCP ports are open. Essentially, the results say the host is up. I checked my firewall rules. Nothing seems wrong with them.

I also checked the Nessus logs, but I don't see any meaningful errors in Nessus's logs.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd recommend here is that you configure a custom Nessus profile for this scan.  Set the ports to be scanned to the two you know are open from the nmap scan and remove the "ping the host" checkbox from the scan profile, so that Nessus doesn't think the hosts are down.

Comment: I set configure to firewall with wrong ip.After the reconfiguration nessus work correctly.But your answer makes sense.